# JMockit tests are being skipped when running them with Maven

Tags: maven, testng, jmockit

When running my TestNG test https://github.com/AffanHasan/reference-artifacts-repository/blob/master/javase/office-desktop/src/test/java/task_item/TaskItem_behaviorTest.java
 containing **JMockit @Mocked objects** it is skipping those tests which contains @Mocked annotated objects as test method parameters

Comment: Check the version of TestNG, it should be 6.2 or newer (6.8 recommended).

Comment: Thanks Rogerio by upgrading the version to 6.8.21 the issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

By upgrading the TestNG version to 6.8.21 the issue is resolved and all the tests are being executed now. Thanks Rogerio!